# How to Compare Each Row in One Column for a Match in Another Column

Tags: google-sheets

I have values in column B and C. All except 4 from column B should have a matching pair in one of the rows from column C.

I tried to use the code `=FILTER(B:B, ISNA(MATCH(B:B, C:C, 0)))` but that only shows me 7 matching values. Any idea why it's not matching the 75 of 79 values?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a **copy** of the actual sample sheet you're using to help people in the community reproduce your setup.

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: Your current `=FILTER(B:B, ISNA(MATCH(B:B, C:C, 0)))` formula seems to only return the values in Column `B` that have **no matching** values in Column `C` as tested on my end. [Removing the `ISNA()` in your function](https://imgur.com/a/VFJcnH7) will return all matching values from columns `B` to `C`, is this your expected result?

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use this formula**

```
=BYROW(B1:B, LAMBDA(x, IF(x="",,IFNA(INDEX( C1:C, MATCH(x, C1:C, 0), 1),"Missing"))))
```

[image]

**Find missing**

```
=IFERROR(FILTER(B:B, ISERROR(MATCH(B:B,C:C  , FALSE))), "No match")
```

[image]

Comment: What I was trying to do was keep Column B in the same order. Then output on Column D the matching values from Column C. That way I can determine the 4 rows from Column B that's missing in Column C.

*Column C has four less rows than Column B.